# Can't register the class AdaptiveCardsBinding.iOS.ACOHostConfig when the dynamic registrar has been linked away

Tags: xamarin.ios-binding

I am creating a Xamarin.iOS binding library for AdaptiveCards. It works correctly on iOS simulator. However, when running on a real iOS device I get the following error: *Can't register the class AdaptiveCardsBinding.iOS.ACOHostConfig when the dynamic registrar has been linked away.*

I have read [this documentation about linker behaviour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos#controlling-the-linker) and tried the following solutions:

1. Set linker behaviour to *Don't Link* in the referencing iOS app. This works but is not efficient/desired
2. Preferred solution: Preserve code by adding the following attribute on the ACOHostConfig class: `[Preserve (AllMembers = true)]` This does not fix the problem.
3. Add mtouch arguments: `--linkskip=AdaptiveCardsBinding.iOS`. Doesn't work either.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

So as the error indicates, the dynamic registrar has been linked away. This default behavior can be overridden by passing --optimize=[+|-]remove-dynamic-registrar to mtouch

**Solution:** Add the following mtouch argument: `--optimize=-remove-dynamic-registrar`